# Child's id is not assigned from parent on persist

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am going through the [Identity Sequencing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Identity_sequencing) strategy and came across below statement

> **Child's id is not assigned from parent on persist.**
>
> A common issue is that the generated Id is part of a child object's Id through a OneToOne or ManyToOne mapping. In this case,
>   because JPA requires that the child define a duplicate Basic mapping
>   for the Id, its Id will be inserted as null. One solution to this is
>   to mark the Column on the Id mapping in the child as `insertable=false`,
>   `updateable=false`, and define the OneToOne or ManyToOne using a normal
>   JoinColumn this will ensure the foreign key field is populated by the
>   OneToOne or ManyToOne not the Basic. Another option is to first
>   persist the parent, then call flush() before persisting the child.

Can someone please explain what the issue the author is trying to convey to us?

Also I see `insertable=false, updateable=false`seems to be like we are making the column as read-only, is that what the attributes mean? Why do we create a column which is just read-only (without insert & update), can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what the author is trying to say is that, in case of parent child relationship, we must persist the child first, then associate the child to the parent and then persist the parent OR let the parent persist the child. This can be done by `insertable=false, updateable=false`.

What `insertable=false, updateable=false` means is that, the responsibility of creating/updating the related entity in question isn't in the child entity. You have a Child and an Parent. You'd like to add insertable=false, updatable=false to the @OneToMany relationship with the Child entity in the Parent entity, simply because it's not the responsibility of the child entity to create or update a Parent. It's the other way round.