# Child's id not present after cascade persisting the parent

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I have a `User` (parent) and a `Home` (child) entities related following a unidirectional one-to-many relationship.

My problem is that, when adding a new `Home` to a `User`, the newly created and persisted `Home` doesn't have the `id`. Is this normal? Do I need to manually persist the child if I want the id?

These are my entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Home.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private List<Home> homes;


    public User() {
    }

    public void addHome(Home home) {
        homes.add(home);
    }
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "home")
public class Home implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "isActive")
    private Boolean isActive;


    public Home() {
    }

}
```

And the code to update the parent:

```
Home home = HomeParser.parse(homeDTO);
User user = userService.findById(userId);
user.addHome(home);
userService.update(user); // delegate call to getEntityManager().merge(user);
```

At this point I assumed I would have `home` to have the id that it's just been given when persisted to db, but it doesn't.

I already tried adding `insertable = false` to the Home's id's `@Column`, as pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32045577/childs-id-is-not-assigned-from-parent-on-persist), but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you add public setters for your private `id` fields? (Would recommend having public getters and setters for all fields.)

Comment: @SteveChambers I removed those in an edit, but I have Lombok Getter and Setter annotations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`EntityManager.merge` method implementation delegates to Hibernate [`Session.merge`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#merge%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Copy the state of the given object onto the persistent object with the
>   same identifier. If there is no persistent instance currently
>   associated with the session, it will be loaded. Return the persistent
>   instance. **If the given instance is unsaved, save a copy of and
>   return it as a newly persistent instance. The given instance does not
>   become associated with the session.** This operation cascades to
>   associated instances if the association is mapped with
>   `cascade="merge"`.

Notice the part in bold. Basically, the `merge` operation will be cascaded to the `Home` instance you created, but Hibernate will create a copy of that instance, merge your instance into the copy, save the copy and replace your instance with the copy in the `User.homes` collection.

After this, `User.homes` collection should contain the copy of the `Home` instance with a properly initialized id.

Comment: Thanks, but that's the problem, the `home` just added to `User.homes` doesn't contain the id even after` merge`. It doesn't replace the original `home` with the copy, because when I debug, the debug-level id doesn't change.

Comment: Could you please add the following code right below `userService.update(user)`: `for (Home home : userService.findById(userId).getHomes()) { System.out.println(home.getId()); }`? What is the output?

Comment: Also, what are transaction boundaries? If they are at the `UserService` level, then the same thing happens to the `user` instance: a copy of it is returned from the `getEntityManager().merge(user)` which contains the managed `Home` instance (which has a properly populated id), and the original `user` instance is not changed in any way. To verify this, you can store the returned user in a separate variable: `User mergedUser = getEntityManager().merge(user)`. Then check if it is the same object instance as the one referenced by the `user` method parameter.

Comment: If I add that printing loop, then the home ids are printed correctly, including the newly-added one. But I wand to avoid having to query the DB again.

Comment: About the boundaries, I have `Transactional` only at `Dao` level. You're right in that the `user` instance returned by `merge()` has a new `home` with a properly populated id. The original and `mergedUser` instance are in fact two different instances.

Comment: Exactly. Then you have to return the result of the `merge` method out of the dao and out of the service: `user = userService.update(user)`. Then use the newly returned user in the rest of the code (that's the standard approach when working with the `merge` method anyway).

Comment: Mr. @Dragan Bozanovic I would have an extra question to that. What if I had a situation where an `A` entity has a reference to `B` (cascade), and `B` has a reference to `C` (also cascade). So when I save the `A` also `B` and `C` supposed to be saved. And I would like to get children `id`s. Do I have to call `merge()` twice in that situation ?

Comment: @user3529850 No, if cascades have been defined, the `merge` operation is propagated from the root through the entire object graph.