# Losing child's ID when serializing parent

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, gwt, one-to-many

I'm trying to build a GWT application which communicates with my already existing REST service built with Spring Boot using JPA, Hibernate, and MySQL. Among others I have two entities: Developer and Team. And a bi-directional OneToMany relation between them. Now I want create a developer and assign him/her to an already existing Team. So I pull a Team via GET request. It gets retrieved with all parameters set. I assign it to a new Developer object. And it still keeps all its parameters. But when I send it all in POST request, ID of the Team gets lost and therefore Hibernate creates a new instance of Team entity. Where am I doing it wrong?

I've seen this post [Child's id not present after cascade persisting the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34227177/childs-id-not-present-after-cascade-persisting-the-parent), but I don't see how I can do the same thing...

GWT Entities:

**Developer**

```
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Developer {

    private final Integer id;
    private final String name;
    private final Team team;

    @JsonCreator
    public Developer(@JsonProperty("id")Integer id, @JsonProperty("name")String name, @JsonProperty("team")Team team){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.team = team;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Team getTeam() {
        return team;
    }

}
```

**Team**

```
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Team {

    private final Integer id;
    private final String name;
    private final List<Developer> developers;
    private final int velocity;

    @JsonCreator
    public Team(@JsonProperty("id")Integer id, @JsonProperty("name")String name, @JsonProperty("velocity")int velocity, @JsonProperty("developers")List<Developer> developers){
        this.id = id;
        this.name=name;
        this.developers = developers;
        this.velocity = velocity;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<Developer> getDevelopers() {
        return developers;
    }

    public int getVelocity() {
        return velocity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Team "+this.getId()+": name="+this.getName()+"; velocity="+this.getVelocity();
    }

}
```

Services:

**TeamService**

```
import org.fusesource.restygwt.client.MethodCallback;
import org.fusesource.restygwt.client.RestService;
import gli.shared.Team;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
/**
 * The client side stub for the RPC service.
 */
@Path("http://localhost:8080/team")
public interface TeamService extends RestService  {

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    void getTeam(@PathParam("id") String id, MethodCallback<Team> team);

    @GET
    void getAllTeams(MethodCallback<List<Team>> teams);

    @GET
    @Path("/random")
    void getRandomTeam(MethodCallback<Team> team);

    @PUT
    @Path("/{id}")
    void updateTeam(@PathParam("id") String id, MethodCallback<String> result);

    @POST
    void addTeam(Team team, MethodCallback<String> result);

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{id}")
    void deleteTeam(@PathParam("id") String id, MethodCallback<String> result);
}
```

**DeveloperService:**

```
import org.fusesource.restygwt.client.MethodCallback;
import org.fusesource.restygwt.client.RestService;
import gli.shared.Developer;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
/**
 * The client side stub for the RPC service.
 */
@Path("http://localhost:8080/developer")
public interface DeveloperService extends RestService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    void getDeveloper(@PathParam("id") String id, MethodCallback<Developer> developer);

    @GET
    void getAllDevelopers(MethodCallback<List<Developer>> developers);

    @GET
    @Path("/team/{id}")
    void getDevelopersByTeam( @PathParam("id") int id, MethodCallback<List<Developer>> developers );

    @PUT
    @Path("/{id}")
    void updateDeveloper(@PathParam("id") String id, MethodCallback<String> result);

    @POST
    void addDeveloper(Developer developer, MethodCallback<String> result);

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{id}")
    void deleteDeveloper(@PathParam("id") String id, MethodCallback<String> result);
}
```

And finally the EntryPoint code:

```
Button addDevButton = new Button(
        "Generate Developer", new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        //Try and get a random team:
        teamService.getRandomTeam(new MethodCallback<Team>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Method method, Throwable throwable) {
                //Developer will not be a part of any team:
                Developer d = new Developer(null, randomName(), null);
                //Send a request to add developer to database:
                devService.addDeveloper(d, new MethodCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Method method, Throwable throwable) {
                        Window.alert("Developer generation has failed for the following reason: \n"+throwable.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Method method, String s) {
                        Window.alert("Developer without a team has been successfully added.");
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Method method, Team team) {
                //Assign developer to this random team:
                Developer d = new Developer(null, randomName(), team);
                Window.alert( d.getTeam().toString());
                //Send a request to add developer to database:
                devService.addDeveloper(d, new MethodCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Method method, Throwable throwable) {
                        Window.alert("Developer generation has failed for the following reason: \n"+throwable.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Method method, String s) {
                        Window.alert("Developer with a team has been successfully added.");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to add setter methods to your Developer and Team classes?

Comment: Sorry for late answer - I had to move to another project and put this one aside. 
Adding setters doesn't help (domain layer of Spring Boot always had them just in case, but I added them for GWT too).
And now I think it's the Resty GWT serializer that messes up.